# jQuery DataTable plugin initialization issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

Sorry for my bad english
I'm having a problem with the datatable jquery plugin in initialization code.

I make an ajax call to reload and update the filtered data in the grid and the plugin returns an error by double initialization

Here is the code

```js
cargarInmuebles(p);
var tablegrid = null;
function cargarInmuebles(params)
{

  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.ajax({
      url: "getXmlInmuebles.php"+params
    }).done(function(data) {

      $('marker',data).each(function() {

        //code reduced... all variables having data

        var itemMarker = ['<img width="141" src="'+imagen+'" height="100" alt="'+idinmueble+'"/>',operacion,dorm,superficie,precio];
        markersArray.push(itemMarker);
        //here markersArray is correct
});
        //here is problem
        if(tablegrid)
        {
          tablegrid.fnDestroy();
          tablegrid = $('#grid-basic').dataTable({
            "data" : markersArray,
            "columns": [
              { "title": "Imagen" },
              { "title": "detalles" },
              { "title": "dorm" },
              { "title": "m2", "class": "center" },
              { "title": "precio", "class": "center" }
            ]
          });
        }
        else
        {
          //twice initialization 
          tablegrid = $('#grid-basic').dataTable({
            "data" : markersArray,
            "columns": [
              { "title": "Imagen" },
              { "title": "detalles" },
              { "title": "dorm" },
              { "title": "m2", "class": "center" },
              { "title": "precio", "class": "center" }
            ]
          });
        }

      });

    });
}
```

Thank you.

EDIT: 
finally it works add this after the first initialization.

tablegrid = jQuery('#grid-basic').dataTable({
          "bDestroy": true
        }).fnDestroy();

Comment: Just call `table.destroy()` instead of `fnDestroy()`

Answer (score 0):

May be, you need to replace:

```
"getXmlInmuebles.php"+params
```

With:

```
"getXmlInmuebles.php?"+params
```

Forgot the `?`?

Comment: No, sorry, is correct because '?' is in params var....the grid is loading the data, but after the first load is when occur the error (cannot reinitialise datatable).

Comment: sorry, error in code, initialization is after .each, ....$('marker',data).each(function() {

        //code reduced... all variables having data

        var itemMarker = ['<img width="141" src="'+imagen+'" height="100" alt="'+idinmueble+'"/>',operacion,dorm,superficie,precio];
        markersArray.push(itemMarker);
        //here markersArray is correct
}//MISSING THIS
        //here is problem
        if(tablegrid)
        {

Comment: @RaulSanchez Update the code in the question buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this otherwise:

I suggest you to initialize `tablegrid` with `false` instead of `null` like one below:

```
var tablegrid=false;
//Other codes
if(!tablegrid)//check not condition first
{
    tablegrid = $('#grid-basic').dataTable({
        "data" : markersArray,
           "columns": [
              { "title": "Imagen" },
              { "title": "detalles" },
              { "title": "dorm" },
              { "title": "m2", "class": "center" },
              { "title": "precio", "class": "center" }
            ]
    });
}
else
{
    tablegrid = $('#grid-basic').dataTable({
        "destroy":true, //Try destroying here
        "data" : markersArray,
        "columns": [
              { "title": "Imagen" },
              { "title": "detalles" },
              { "title": "dorm" },
              { "title": "m2", "class": "center" },
              { "title": "precio", "class": "center" }
            ]
    });
}
```

Comment: the problem is in ajax call , Because if i use the code in separate js file, it works . But i don´t know what is the best method for to load datatable inside the .done jquery method